# Best way to sync file between iphone and mac

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, itunes

I have recently moved from Android to iPhone 7 plus 128 GB and I thought to use this space by transferring files from my Mac to iPhone.

However, I don't know how I dod it. It was easier for Android, just plug the phone and drag-drop.

This may seem like a stupid question but any help is appreciated. I just want to transfer my music files and PDFs (ebooks, other documents).

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to adopt iCloud sync unless you can’t allow these files to have their “truth” copy be stored online.

- https://www.apple.com/icloud/

In the past - the cloud sync had some cases where it wouldn’t work for very common situations, but now those reservations are all edge cases in my eyes.

You can use your documents folder / desktop folder and expect everything to sync up to the cloud. This includes finder color metadata, smart tags, as well as content and normal metadata (last opened, created, size, etc...)

On iOS - the files app is somewhat basic, but I expect it to iterate rapidly as people decide how to use it and Apple adapts the layout and training so people can use the tools.

The underlying sync seems quite solid in my experience the last 2 years with improvements made each month along the way. I have about 120 GB of files stored and am delighted with the performance now that I have an always-on Mac Mini running [iCloud content caching](https://www.imore.com/speed-icloud-access-macos-high-sierra-content-caching) on my home and work networks. Restores of 128 GB to a full iPhone that used to take day(s) now takes hour(s) with most of the restore functional after 60 minutes. You don’t need caching, but it’s there for power users or people with slower network access speeds or worried about restores pushing them over a data usage limit.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way of transferring those files is to use iTunes on your Mac.

Add the music and ebooks to your iTunes library and then select them to be synced to your iPhone. Apple's support article on the topic has the details: [Sync your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iTunes on your computer using USB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201253).

You can also use other transports such as for example storing your ebooks and PDFs on iCloud Drive, DropBox or similar - and then accessing them from the iPhone via the cloud.

Or you could use AirDrop to transfer PDFs to your iPhone and open them in iBooks.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn’t work. I opened the music file on my Mac, by default in iTunes. Then I plugged my iPhone to my Mac. But I don’t see an option to transfer the file from Mac to iPhone. I tried AirDrop but that just asks me to open the file in Dropbox, OneDrive etc. I would prefer to have all my music in one folder so I can play it.

Comment: You have to import the file to your iTunes library, not just play it https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19613?locale=en_US and how to transfer the files to the iPhone https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201253

Answer (score 0):

using an original apple cable when iphone is plugged in your mac on itune appear an iphone icon, selecting it by accessing your iphone management